# Sorting 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

The input.txt contains data like this:

```
> NUMBER OF PARTICIPANTS
> NAME - SCORE
> NAME - SCORE
```

etc etc.

But my sorting lines doesn't put the names with according score. Where should i put the Name[] array in this sorting lines so that it would sort name and score together in descending order?

```
#define MAX 15
 int main(void)

{
    int N;

FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");                          
if(!file)
{
    fputs("Error opening file, exiting.", stderr);           
    return -1;
}

if(fscanf(file, "%d", &N) != 1)                                 
{
    fputs("Error finding first number; Exiting.", stderr);  
    return -1;
}

printf("Participants: %d\n", N);                                
printf("\n");   

char name[N][MAX];                                              
double Skoor[N];                                                
int i=0;                                                        

while(i < N && fscanf(file,"%s %lf", name[i], &Skoor[i]) == 2)  
{
    printf("Participant #%d: %s  ", i + 1, name[i]);                
    printf("  | %2.2f\n", Skoor[i]);                            
    i++;
}

fclose(file);                                                   

printf("\n");

int j, a;        //Sorting starts                                               
for (i = 0; i < N;++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
    {
        if (Skoor[i] < Skoor[j])
        {
            a =  Skoor[i];   
            Skoor[i] = Skoor[j];
            Skoor[j] = a;
        }
    }
}

printf("Winners listed by score: \n");                  
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)                                         
printf(" #%d place - %s - %2.2lf\n",i+1, name[i], Skoor[i]);
```

Comment: Exchange coresssponding elements of `name` when you exchange elements of `Skoor`.

Comment: edited code, #define MAX 15

Comment: Note that local variables are placed on the stack for most implementations and its space is limited. On full-grown OSse this is typically some MiB. So don't let the VLA become too large. Note 2: Using variables like `N` is a bad idea for two reasone: all-upper case names aore typically macros in C. 2) The name is not self-explanatory. Use names which describe what the object means, e.g. `num_entries` here. That makes your code much more readable and understandable, thus less error-prone. (same for `MAX`: `MAX`-what? But here upper-case is fine)

Comment: Declare `char tmp[MAX];` and then, in the body of the `if`, use `strcpy(temp, name[i]); strcpy(name[i], name[j]); strcpy(name[j], tmp);`